# How can we prove that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group in $R^{4}$

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups

A group is called topological group if it satisfies three properties

1) G is a Hausdorff space in K
(Here we want to prove that if $ A,B \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ then we can find two disjoint open sets $F,G$ in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $ A \in F,B \in G $

2)Multiplicative mapping is continuous (That is if $f :GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ x $ GL(2,\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ defined as $f((A,B))=AB$ then $f$ is continuous- Corresponding to open set $V \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ (in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$) , $f^{-1}(V)$ open in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ x $ GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ (in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ x$\mathbb{R}^{4}$).

3)Inverse map is continuous ($g :GL(2,\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow  GL(2,\mathbb{R}) $ defined as $ g(A)=A^{-1}$.Corresponding to $V $ open $\in  \mathbb{R}^{4}$  $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in  $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

What will be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ ?

How can we prove that these open set contains a matrix $A$ ( surely 2x2 and non singular) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify the three properties:

1) $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of the Hausdorff space $\mathbb{R}^4$ (assuming it's given the obvious topology).

2) For $A, B\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, each index $(AB)_{ij}$ is a polynomial in the $A_{pq}$ and $B_{pq}$ and thus continuous.

3) For $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ entries in the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ are of the form $A_{ij} = p_{ij}/(\det A)$ for some polynomial $p_{ij}$ in the entries $A_{pq}$. The determinant $\det A$ is also a polynomial in the entries of $A$ and nonzero.

If I understand your question after the edit, you're asking about showing that any point in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has a neighborhood meeting $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (which isn't related to whether $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group). Since $\det A = A_{11} A_{22} - A_{12} A_{21}$ is a polynomial in the $A_{ij}$, any neighborhood of a point $A\in \mathbb{R}^4$ contains a point $A'$ with $\det A'\not = 0$; that is, $A'\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail.But still I have some doubts (may be silly) 1)what will be the structure of open sets  in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ (Like Open sets in $mathbb{R}^{2}$ are open discs) 2) $A$ is a 2x2 non singular matrix with real entries.How can we prove that $A$ belongs to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ ?

Comment: First of all I want to show that every disjoint points in $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R}$ contained in disjoint open sets in $ \mathbb{R}^{4}$ For answering this question I need two things 1)what will be the structure of open sets  in $ \mathbb{R}^{4} $ (Like Open sets in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ are open discs) 2) $A$ is a 2x2 non singular matrix with real entries.How can we prove that $A$ belongs to an open set in $ \mathbb{R}^{4} $ ? I don't know whether I am moving in right direction or not.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a metric space; its topology is generated by open balls. For your second comment: (1) follows immediately from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^4$ is Hausdorff; (2) $A\in \mathbb{R}^4$.